# Suit for Titan Life

Tags: colonization, titan

I was wondering what suit I'd need for Titan, The design of the Suit, and the oxygen system of the Suit? I know that you'd need a suit that can keep you warm and supply oxygen but how would it do it? What's the most efficient way?

Comment: See these previous posts: [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2599/could-an-eva-suit-meant-for-mars-be-used-for-eva-on-another-celestial-or-vice-v), [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29967/how-do-i-dress-for-a-hike-on-a-hot-summer-day-on-titan/29984), [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32846/how-would-humans-with-appropriate-equipment-travel-the-surface-of-saturns-moon/32856), [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34527/titan-vs-mars-for-colonization/34560).

Comment: I don't see how this "needs more focus" and no close voter has bothered to provide any help by leaving even a short comment. One nice answer already has been able to address the full scope of the question already. **Voting to leave open** because the question is already easily answerable as is, no need for an answer-blocking closing and reopening cycle here.

Answer (score 2):

[Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon))'s atmosphere is has about 1.5 times the surface pressure of Earth's, so there would be no need for a pressure suit and it's mainly nitrogen, so not especially toxic. Something like a divers' dry suit would be a good place to start. You would need to find a material for the suit that remained flexible at low temperatures, which might be a challenge, and you would some combinations of insulating layers and electrically heated layers inside that. You'd probably want knee and elbow pads and boots outside the suit to prevent punctures and provide additional insulation. Inside the suit you'd have air at ambient pressure (or just slightly greater to keep the insulation from being flattened).

As for air supply, again underwater diving technology is probably the place to start. You could use bottled oxygen and a [rebreather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebreather) type setup, or pre-mix the oxygen with nitrogen (easily available from the atmosphere) and have a simpler setup, but with bulkier tanks for the same duration of mission.  Oxygen would come from melting and electrolyzing the surface ice, so you would need plenty of power. The tanks would need to be heated a bit to keep the oxygen gaseous (or they could contain liquid oxygen under pressure, which might increase capacity) and the oxygen would need to be heated before you breathed it. The valve, hoses, etc. would all need to be either made from cold-tolerant materials or heated.

Comment: It has a lot of cyanides, so, yes, it is toxic.